# Exception with Pandas on secondary computer

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I had no issues on one computer, but moving to a server, the same code is hitting Pandas issues. I did a `conda env update` and `git pull`. Both are up to date. Surely some similar setup issue must still be the issue, but I can't figure out what.

pandas versions are the same on both:

```
pip list | grep pandas 
pandas                            0.23.0
pandas-summary                    0.0.41 
sklearn-pandas                    1.6.0
```

*AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.common' has no attribute 'is_numeric_dtype'*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-5fc2f9e3ed3e> in <module>()
----> 1 DataFrameSummary(tables[4])

~/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_summary/__init__.py in __init__(self, df)
     25         self.df = df
     26         self.length = len(df)
---> 27         self.columns_stats = self._get_stats()
     28         self.corr = df.corr()
     29 

~/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_summary/__init__.py in _get_stats(self)
     87         # settings types
     88         stats['types'] = ''
---> 89         columns_info = self._get_columns_info(stats)
     90         for ctype, columns in columns_info.items():
     91             stats.ix[columns, 'types'] = ctype

~/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_summary/__init__.py in _get_columns_info(self, stats)
    109                                         self.EXCLUDE,
    110                                         column_info['constant'].union(column_info['bool']))
--> 111         column_info[self.TYPE_NUMERIC] = pd.Index([c for c in rest_columns
    112                                                    if common.is_numeric_dtype(self.df[c])])
    113         rest_columns = self.get_columns(self.df[rest_columns], self.EXCLUDE, column_info['numeric'])

~/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_summary/__init__.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    110                                         column_info['constant'].union(column_info['bool']))
    111         column_info[self.TYPE_NUMERIC] = pd.Index([c for c in rest_columns
--> 112                                                    if common.is_numeric_dtype(self.df[c])])
    113         rest_columns = self.get_columns(self.df[rest_columns], self.EXCLUDE, column_info['numeric'])
    114         column_info[self.TYPE_DATE] = pd.Index([c for c in rest_columns

AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.common' has no attribute 'is_numeric_dtype'
```

Comment: Isn't that under `pandas.api.types`?

Comment: Also are you sure pip is listing libraries in  your fastai environment?

Comment: I don't follow the pandas.api.types comment. Can you elaborate a bit? Confirmed pip is the env's pip: `which pip
/root/anaconda3/envs/fastai/bin/pip`

Comment: The traceback shows `is_numeric_dtype` is being imported from `pandas.core.common` but as far as I know it is currently under `pandas.api.types`. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype.html). Maybe you've updated your pandas but not the other libraries that depend on older versions of pandas? It seems the error is coming from `pandas_summary` package. Is that up to date?

Comment: Yeah, it seems the fix was [merged](https://github.com/mouradmourafiq/pandas-summary/pull/11) last week. I think it will be resolved when you update that package.

Comment: a month later and the fixed version hasn't been released yet. Install the dev version to fix that: `pip install git+https://github.com/mouradmourafiq/pandas-summary`

Answer (score 1):

pandas.core.common.is_numeric_dtype was removed in 0.23.

Go to the

```
/anaconda3/envs/fastai-cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_summary/__init__.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    110                                         column_info['constant'].union(column_info['bool']))
    111         column_info[self.TYPE_NUMERIC] = pd.Index([c for c in rest_columns
--> 112                                                    if common.is_numeric_dtype(self.df[c])])
    113         rest_columns = self.get_columns(self.df[rest_columns], self.EXCLUDE, column_info['numeric'])
    114         column_info[self.TYPE_DATE] = pd.Index([c for c in rest_columns
```

and change the `common` to `types`.

Also, add `from pandas.api import types` to the beginning of the file.

---

Alternatively, downgrade to 0.22